# C Program: matching array of strings when length is known at compile time versus when it's not known

Tags: c

I have a working C program where the length of an array of strings is known at compile time. It is:

```
char array_person_name[3][101];
char person_name[101] = "";
...
strncpy(person_name, "John Smith", strlen("John Smith")+1 );
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    sprintf(array_person_name[i], person_name );
}
```

When I check the first element using gdb it reads (e.g. "John Smith" + null character):

```
(gdb) p array_person_name[0]  
$1 = "John Smith", '\000' <repeats 26 times>, "\003\000\t\000p\005\240 ?", '\000' <repeats 11 times>, "@\337\377\377\377\177\000\000\260\337\377\377\377\177\000\000\001\000\000\000\000\000\000\000\300\332\377\377\377\177\000\000\000\235\230Z5\000\000\000\260\337\377\377\377"
```

All the other elements in the array look similar. Now I need to modify this program so it works when the array size is not known at run time, where the result needs to be exactly the same as what is printed from gdb above (except, the characters after the null may be different). Here's my code:

```
char **array_person_name;
char person_name[101] = "";
...
strncpy(person_name, "John Smith", strlen("John Smith")+1 );
array_person_name = malloc(3 * sizeof(char*)); /* allocate memory for row pointers */
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
  array_person_name[i] = malloc(101 * sizeof(char)); /* allocate memory for columns */
  sprintf(array_person_name[i], person_name );
}
```

When I then check the first element using gdb, it reads:

```
(gdb) p array_person_name[0]
$1 = 0x6cff30 "John Smith"
```

I'm not exactly sure what the difference between these two programs' gdb outputs are, but whatever difference there is, is enough for a shared library, which accepts `array_person_email` as an input, to perform correctly for the first code block and incorrectly for the second code block. Is there a way to modify my second code block so that `array_person_email` looks the same as what results from the first code block?

Comment: `sprintf(person_name[i], person_name );`?  Shouldn't that be `sprintf(array_person_name[i], person_name );` in both cases?

Comment: Also, this is not a safe use of `sprintf` (in general).  If you just want to copy strings, then use `strcpy`/`strncpy`.

Comment: yes, good catch, it's a typo here (my code has the right varaible)-- I'll update...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the output in GDB looks different is because in the first case, the `array_person_name[0]` is an array whose size is known at compile-time, so GDB endeavours to display everything it knows about that array (i.e. all 101 elements).  If you instead did `p (char *)array_person_name[0]`, you would only get the "relevant" portion of the array.

If your library function exhibits different behaviour, then either it's broken, or you're not passing it what it expects (i.e. it's expecting something other than a `char **`).

Comment: Interesting. Here's what I get: `(gdb)  p (char *)array_person_name[0]
$1 = 0x7fffffffd900 "John Smith"` The address size is longer, likely explained by @stefan bachert's comment as one being from stack versus heap. An earlier answer talked about the first case being an array of array char's and the second case being an array of strings. Is there any way to modify the second case to have it be an array of array chars? The library is expecting a `(char *)` to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: @ggkmath: There isn't really any such thing as a string in C.  There's merely an array of chars, one of which is a null-terminator.  I see now that this is an extension of your question from yesterday, with that dodgy library function!  If the function expects a `char *` pointing at a contiguous 1D array of concatenated "strings", then passing an array of pointers definitely won't work.

Comment: OK, then it's just symantics at this point... would you say the two arrays appear similar from a program point of view and it's just how the array is fed into the library that is likely the issue?

Comment: @ggkmath: If the function is expecting a `char **`, then a true 2D array and a dynamically-allocated array of pointers should appear identical to it.  If it's expecting a `char *`, then either will invoke undefined behaviour.

Comment: The first case is a true 2D array, so I'd accept that as the standard.  The author's example code is here http://orclib.sourceforge.net/doc/html/group__g__bind.html#ga502cd4785691b17955f5d99276e48884 under "Array Interface Example", you might recall from my earlier post. I believe it wants to see a `(char *)` as input. Is there a way to add a `*` or a `&` or something else to `array_person_name` to feed the function a `(char *)`?

Comment: @ggkmath: Indeed.  But like I said at the time, if the author of that library is treating a true 2D array as a 1D array, then it will cause undefined behaviour (although it may happen to work in all situations).  You never followed up with the results of the suggestions to your question from yesterday; what happened when you tried constructing the giant 1D array?

Comment: I tried the 1D array approach and it didn't work. I started from scratch, getting the author's code to work as he intended (that's the first code block above, which is a 2D array, and it works fine). You might notice that I changed the `strncpy` to a `sprintf` to match the author's code. I intended to change it back once things were working.

Comment: @ggkmath: Ok.  Well, an array of pointers to dynamically-allocated arrays can never be made to work if the library is really expecting a contiguous buffer, because they won't be contiguous.

Comment: So, is one difference between the 2 code blocks above is that the first code block is one contiguous buffer and the second code block is not? If so, then perhaps this explains why your original thought was to create one large 1D array?

Comment: Hmm, and they are both an array of strings as you said earlier, so, is this the only difference you see between them, besides one from stack vs heap?

Comment: @ggkmath: Stack vs. heap should make no difference.  So yes, the only difference is that the first example is contiguous.  But then the giant 1D array is also contiguous...

Comment: OK, thanks for helping me understand it better. I really appreciate your comments!

Answer (score 1):

In the first example the debugger prints out all the characters of the array, and in the second example the debugger doesn't have a size so only prints the zero-terminated string.

Answer (score 1):

array_person_name[i] is not initialized in both cases.

First version takes the stack, second the heap. Maybe statistical differences causes different behavior. However, you should initialize in both cases

Comment: How to initialize? Is `array_person_name[i]="";` a good way? Or, perhaps I should use `calloc` instead of `malloc`?

Comment: That would be totally wrong, you would override the allocated pointer with an pointer to `char = 0`. Use `array_person_name[i] = 0`; or `strcpy (array_person_name[i], "String"); // best with n`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't understand your comment, "// best with n"?

Comment: in real use the variant strncpy to avoid buffer overflow

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
p array_person_name[0]
```

try

```
ptype array_person_name[0]
```

and compare the type of the two variables.

You will notice they are not the same.

and by the way, I have to say

```
strncpy(person_name, "John Smith", strlen("John Smith")+1 );
```

is a bug, I think you meant:

```
strncpy(person_name, "John Smith", 101);
```